# Nothing dumped from json that converted from bson

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I need your help about nlohmann's json library.
I wrote this code.

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t> v = nlohmann::json::to_bson(jInit);
std::vector<std::uint8_t> s;
for (auto& i : v)
{
    s.push_back(v[i]);
}
std::ofstream ofs(s_basePath + "dump.txt");
ofs << nlohmann::json::from_bson(s).dump();
```

This simply converts json to bson, then convert the bson to json and dump it as a text file.

For some reasons, I have to use push_back() and get json back.

The problem is, size of the dumped text file is 0 kb, nothing will be dumped.

I tried also this code and it is working.

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t> v = nlohmann::json::to_bson(jInit);
std::ofstream ofs(s_basePath + "dump.txt");
ofs << nlohmann::json::from_bson(v).dump();
```

I have no idea what's the difference between vector v and s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with [json](/questions/tagged/json)/[bson](/questions/tagged/bson). It's just that you use every `uint8_t` in the original [bson](/questions/tagged/bson) data as an *index* into the very same data, which scrambles everything up.

Wrong:

```cpp
for (auto& i : v)
{
    s.push_back(v[i]); // `i` is not an index
}
```

The correct loop should look like this:

```cpp
for (auto& i : v)
{
    s.push_back(i);    // `i` is a reference to the actual data you should put in `s`
}
```

If you need a copy of the vector with the [bson](/questions/tagged/bson) data, you can simply copy it though:

```cpp
s = v;
```